# How to get unity to stream a camera for a Google Cardboard project?

Tags: google-cardboard

I am trying to get Unity (version 5.0.1f1) to stream a live feed from a camera for a Google Cardboard project at my university. The live feed I plan to use is from a single GoPro Hero 3 camera which I plan to duplicate the image.

I just wanted to know if this is a feasible idea with Unity or any other program, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Matthew

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this, but if you can get the GoPro to act as a WebCam, you can try using a WebCamTexture in Unity.

Getting GoPro to act as a webcam:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltxPZuIC6mk

Be sure to read the comment by "webzkey" who explains how to do it.

Unity WebCamTexture:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.html

No guarantees this will work, but worth a shot.

Note: you do not necessarily have to duplicate the image.  Just put the texture on a plane and place that in front of the camera at a comfortable distance.

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly and thanks for the good advise. I will reply when I have tried this.